# The LINQ expression could not be translated when trying to combine two expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

Trying to combine two expressions into a single one. First expression loks following:

```
Expression<Func<Course, bool>> courseStatusFilter = c => c.Status == status;
```

second expression, that must ignore case on comparison of two strings, looks following:

```
Expression<Func<Course, bool>> nameFilter = c => c.Name.Equals(courseName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Combine expression get following exception on executing:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(c => (Nullable)c.Status
> == (Nullable)__status_0 && c.Name.Equals( value: __courseName_1, comparisonType: CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))' could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

But executing works fine when second expression looks following:

```
Expression<Func<Course, bool>> nameFilter = c => c.Name == courseName;
```

Following code doing expression combination:

```
Expression<Func<Course, bool>> nameFilter = c => c.Name == courseName;
var body = Expression.Invoke(nameFilter, courseStatusFilter?.Parameters);
courseStatusFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Course, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(courseStatusFilter.Body, body), courseStatusFilter.Parameters);
```

How can I using `Equals` method for string comparison in my case and what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if this will work for you, but try: `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. 'CurrentCulture' is a .net thing that can't be translated to database.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1222

Comment: The LINQ statement will be converted to a SQL statement and send to the server. SQL doesn't support to distinguish between case-sensitive and case-insensitive comparision. Which one will be taken depends on the collation set in the database.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?